# Parse JSON in children element in order

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, parsing

Here is the JSON example:

jsonData:

```json
{ "Device": { "Content": { "UL": { "index0": "12", "index1": "1", .... "index31": "5", } } } }
```

This is what I tried, but it didn't work:

```javascript
var index = [];
var jsonDoc = JSON.parse(data);
for(var i =0; i<32 ; i++)
{
  var $arr = "index"+i;
  index.push( jsonDoc.Device.Content.UL.$arr);
}
```

How can I extract the index from 1 to 31 and put it in the index array?

Comment: `,,,,UL[$arr]` is likely what you want

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7102704/how-to-use-variables-in-dot-notation-like-square-bracket-notation - sorry about the commas above

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4255389/javascript-object-notation-with-variable

Comment: Explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20736758/difference-between-dot-notation-and-bracket-notation-in-javascript

Answer (score 1):

You can access hashes with the [] operator as well:

```
index.push( jsonDoc.Device.Content.UL[$arr]);
```

Comment: @mplungjan, it has an explanation and a solution with working code. What do you miss?

Comment: Huge duplicate and already answered in my comment - I know you did not see it but should be closed

Comment: @Gavriel this the only way to access values when you have key reference in a var. `key[var]`.

Comment: @Jai, right, the "as well" I meant that jsonDoc["Device"]["Content"]["UL"][$arr] would work as well for example. In places where you have variables, you don't have another choice

Answer (score 1):

try converting JSON to array .

```
var o = jsonDoc.Device.Content.UL;
var arr = Object.keys(o).map(function(k) { return o[k] });
```

refer: [Converting JSON Object into Javascript array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20881213/converting-json-object-into-javascript-array)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `for` statement to iterate through an object's values:

```
var index = [];
for(var name in jsonDoc.Device.Content.UL) 
{ 
    index.push(jsonDoc.Device.Content.UL[name])); 
}
```